# Is there a name for a word that physically sounds the same backwards and forwards?

Tags: single-word-requests

Not a word that reads the same, a word that actually *sounds* the same whether it's pronounced forwards or backwards.

Comment: I'd call it an "aha moment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Phonetic palindromes:**](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Phonetic_palindrome.html)

> A phonetic palindrome is a portion of sound or phrase of speech that is identical or roughly identical when reversed.
>
> Some phonetic palindromes must be mechanically reversed, involving the use of sound recording equipment or reverse tape effects. Another, more abstract type, are words that are identical to the original when separated into their phonetic components (according to a system such as the International Phonetic Alphabet) and reversed.
>
> In English, certain written palindromes also happen to be phonetic palindromes, particularly monosyllabic ones such as mom, dad, and pip. However, this does not guarantee that a reversed recording of any of these words will sound identical to non-reversed speech, because certain pronunciations can cause a shift in the articulation of the vowel, differentiating the beginning from the end in its pitch.

[ipfs.io]